# How to pass dynamic scope params to Ruby on Rails Mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In my Rails 7 app I have the following routes set up:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope 'account/:current_account' do

      resources :clients

  end

end
```

This will, for example, generate a route like this:

```
/account/:current_account/clients(.:format)
```

In my ApplicationController I have `url_options` set up in order to keep `@current_account` in every request.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  def url_options
    {:current_account => @current_account}.merge(super)
  end

end
```

This works fine throughout the entire app, **except** in all the mailers.

Whenever I try to trigger an email I am getting this error:

```
possible unmatched constraints: [:current_account]
```

How can I get this working with all my Mailers too?

Answer (score 0):

In the mailer you can use the following:

```
class ClientMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def welcome_email(client)
    @client = client
    @account = Account.find(params[:current_account])
    mail(to: @client.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

This will pass the current_account to the mailer.